# Trying to build simple file uploader facebook application

Tags: python, facebook, dropbox, dropbox-api, uploader

long time lurker, first time question askerer. Please excuse any typos as I have an inverse relationship between coffee consumed and typing accuracy.

What I am trying to do is create a simple uploader application for a fan facebook page. I have decided to write it in Python as, well, it's the only language that I know, and is supported by FB Dev.

The goals for this application are pretty modest:

1. Users should be able to simply click on a box that will open a dialogue to select a file on their hard drive and upload it to a cloud (I've settled on dropbox, more on this later)
2. The uploader should only accept specific file extensions.
3. Users should be able to browse and be able to download said files.
4. The application should be able to detect flood attempts, and in an ideal world be able to detect which facebook user is uploading them. (It's a sad indictment of my coding "skills" that the second half of this goal is a stretch target).
5. Users should be able to ideally be able to move files cloud to cloud, as well as cloud to disk. This isn't as important.

Okay, so now that I've laid out the aims for my magnum opus, I'll follow up with where I'm at, before humbling approaching the Overflow Gods for guidance.

So first of all I created an account on Heroku, and created the application there. It's basically sitting there at the moment, with no code in it what so ever.

After this I began looking over the web for simple Python file uploaders. After searching around, I found this code on the DropBox dev site. So I went through the signup for a dropbox SDK, and had to install "setup tools' via this http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools 
I used the ez_setup.py and simply ran that which seemed to get past the "setuptools module" not found error.

I've posted the code below.

```
# Include the Dropbox SDK libraries
from dropbox import client, rest, session

# Get your app key and secret from the Dropbox developer website
APP_KEY = 'xxxxxetc.'
APP_SECRET = 'xxxxxetc.'

# ACCESS_TYPE should be 'dropbox' or 'app_folder' as configured for your app
ACCESS_TYPE = 'dropbox'

sess = session.DropboxSession(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, ACCESS_TYPE)

request_token = sess.obtain_request_token()

# Make the user sign in and authorize this token
url = sess.build_authorize_url(request_token)
print "url:", url
print "Please authorize in the browser. After you're done, press enter."
raw_input()

# This will fail if the user didn't visit the above URL and hit 'Allow'
access_token = sess.obtain_access_token(request_token)

client = client.DropboxClient(sess)
print "linked account:", client.account_info()

f = open('working-draft.txt')
response = client.put_file('/magnum-opus.txt', f)
print "uploaded:", response

folder_metadata = client.metadata('/')
print "metadata:", folder_metadata

f, metadata = client.get_file_and_metadata('/magnum-opus.txt',rev='362e2029684fe')
out = open('magnum-opus.txt', 'w')
out.write(f.read())
print(metadata)
```

Hereafter I have arrived at the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Python27/FAUploader (Roaring-gorge)/Roaringgorge101", line 2, in <module>
    from dropbox import client, rest, session
  File "F:\Python27\dropbox\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import client, rest, session
  File "F:\Python27\dropbox\client.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .rest import ErrorResponse, RESTClient
  File "F:\Python27\dropbox\rest.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

I'm beginning to get a little bit worried that this may be travelling in the wrong direction & I'm not very good at coding, and even worse at asking for help. So I'm just going to post this now before I spend too long trying to make my question too perfect. I am really into learning coding, and if you guys could help me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated. It just seems everyone, even people with little experience, are capable of completing these kinds of projects much faster than I am.

These are the references I've been using/sites I've been visiting

https://www.dropbox.com/developers

I was not allowed to post more hyperlinks, as I am too noob, apparently. '-_-

Anyways I digress, any help would be much appreciated.

## EDIT/Progress Report

So I managed to update the Python enviroment to get past the error described in the post above. However I've only managed to succeed in getting a new one that confuses me a bit more.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python27\FAUploader (Roaring-gorge)\Roaringgorge101", line 22, in <module>
    access_token = sess.obtain_access_token(request_token)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\dropbox\session.py", line 205, in obtain_access_token
    response = self.rest_client.POST(url, headers=headers, params=params, raw_response=True)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\dropbox\rest.py", line 260, in POST
    return cls.IMPL.POST(*n, **kw)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\dropbox\rest.py", line 207, in POST
    post_params=params, headers=headers, raw_response=raw_response)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\dropbox\rest.py", line 183, in request
    raise ErrorResponse(r)
ErrorResponse: [401] u'Token is disabled or invalid'
>>>
```

I tried mucking around with DropBox directly seeing if there was anything in the application that might help me with all this, but the code, my browser, and the dropbox app all seem to completely ignore each other.

Once again much help appreciated. I think I might go bang my head against some SQL for a while.

Comment: When one is aware of an inverse relation between coffee consumption and typing ability it behooves one to proof-read one's posts more carefully in proportion to the amount of coffee consumed.

Comment: you should know that your post is waaaay too long for 99.9% of readers

Comment: @wroniasty: His post is long, but it'll help him get a good answer. Some questions are very specific and require some context to be answered. It has introduction, explicit requirements and the OP's own considerations and researching efforts. I think this is a great first question on SO.

Comment: still, I was halfway through my second coffee by the time I finished reading it (I'm a slow reader I guess ;). But seriously - it is a good question, just a little longish.

Answer (score 2):

Execute the setup tools script as follows

```
curl http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py | python
```

This should take care of that error

> ImportError: No module named pkg_resources

The rest of the plan sounds like it *should* work as Heroku's free package wouldn't have the space to hold those files

> an ideal world be able to detect which facebook user is uploading them

Just authenticate via Facebook Authentication flows http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ and you can then log the current user with

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=xxx
```

With Facebook Python library like facepy

```
pip install facepy
```

it works like

```
from facepy import GraphAPI
graph = GraphAPI('your_access_token_goes_here')
graph.get('me')
```

There is logic missing here such as the auth to a web page like Dropbox did but this is the general gist.

So everything looks okay so far, I don't think you are at the stage of Facebook API checks now as this is a Dropbox API problem and Python setuptools issue

Comment: Hey oops pasted that without context, sorry, not sure how that happened, waywayrd enter perhaps. 

So I updated the python environment as you described, also went out and and got virtualenv & pip, but now it's throwing up the error described in the pastebin above. Also should I update the OP to reflect progress or comment down, like a forum ?

Answer (score 0):

Response to the ErrorResponse: [401] u'Token is disabled or invalid' was getting the same thing in my code

From the Dropbox API:
**In the case where a token is no longer authorized, the REST API will return an HTTP Error 401 Unauthorized response**

I copied the generated link and authorized the app again to get my code to work :)